# Encadeamento de pipelines

Tags: jenkins, groovy, integração-contínua, pipeline

Tenho dois jobs no jenkins (`A` e `B`). Oq preciso é que o job `A`, após terminar, inicie a execução do job `B`. Sendo que preciso da aprovação de um usuário para que isso ocorra.

```
//algo do tipo
executarJobB = input(
    message: "Devo iniciar o job B",
    ok: "Encadear",
    submitterParameter: 'executarJobB')

if (executarJobB) {
    build job: "B", parameters: [[$class: 'String', name: 'image', value: $image ]]
}
```

- Como posso fazer isso?
- Como executar esse código após o pipeline `A` ter sido executado com sucesso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variavel `executarJobB` não é necessaira.
Se o usuario aceitar com `Encadear` o job continua e passa direto pro `build`.
Porém se ele cancelar, o build falha. Então talvez você nao queria isso, o que pode ser resolvido com um `try-catch`.

Para verificar se um job foi executado com sucesso até um determinado momento voce pode fazer isso, que retorna um boolean:

Deixando teu código assim:

```
if (currentBuild.resultIsBetterOrEqualTo("SUCCESS")) {
    try {
       input message: "Devo iniciar o job", ok: "Encadear"

       build job: "B", parameters: [[$class: 'String', name: 'image', value: $image]]
   } catch (ignored) {
       echo "Job B não foi lançado pelo usuário"
   }
}
```